# Difference between e.Handeld = true and unsubscribing from event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have an event handler that for some reason (I don't understand) get called twice, I thought that setting `e.Handled = true` will solve it but it doesn't, finally I unsubscribed from the event inside the handler, and it works:

```
((FabTabItem)sender).TabClosing -= oTab_TabClosing;
```

So I have these questions:

- What is the difference between the both approches, Don't they stop handling the event?
- Is it OK to unsubscribe from the event inside its handler since its natural to say "stop listening to the event after it's been handled"? (I don't see this a lot)

Comment: One-shot event handling probably isn't as uncommon as you'd think. If that's your goal, then I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: When you have several handlers for the one event they are called in series. If one of the handlers thinks that it has "handled" the event and no further handlers need to do anything it can set `e.Handled = true`. It is up to the subsequent handlers to honour this flag and not do any processing - but they are still called. Also this doesn't change the handling for when the next time the event is raised - all of the handlers get called again.

Answer (score 1):

From the following MSDN page on the [`KeyPressEventArgs.Handled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.handled(v=vs.110).aspx) Property:

> If the event is not handled, it will be sent to the operating system for default processing.

So setting it to `true` means that any further processing of the event will not happen for the rest of that call to the event depending on how the other events handle the `Handled` property. As @Enigmativity put it in the comments to the OP:

> When you have several handlers for the one event they are called in series. If one of the handlers thinks that it has "handled" the event and no further handlers need to do anything it can set e.Handled = true. It is up to the subsequent handlers to honour this flag and not do any processing - but they are still called. Also this doesn't change the handling for when the next time the event is raised - all of the handlers get called again.

By unsubscribing from the event the rest of the actions in the event still occur, in the case of the above mentioned event it still goes through to the operating system.

The two scenarios you described are not exactly the same.

Unsubscribing from the event inside the handler itself is fine, all it does is remove the call to that handler next time the event is raised.

With that said if you are doing this because the event is being called more times than it should be you should probably track down where the event is being subscribed too. It is likely you have accidentally subscribed the same handler twice and that is the proper fix rather than hacking around it by unsubscribing from the event.

Comment: The line "So setting it to true means that any further processing of the event will not happen for the rest of that call to the event" isn't true. It contradicts my comment that you quoted.

Comment: @Enigmativity I worded that slightly wrong, I'll edit. And sorry about ripping off your comment but you worded it better than I could!

Comment: No worries. As long as I get attributed (as you did) I don't mind being ripped off. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between the both approaches, Don't they sop handling the event?

e.Handled = true; indicates that the event handler has already processed the event and dealt with it, so it doesn't need to be processed any further. In other words, please don't take any further action.

but the second will Remove Event and Don,t happen next time

> Is it OK to unsubscribe from the event inside its handler since its natural to say "stop listening to the event after it's been handled"? (I don't see this a lot)

its depend to your Roll if you want not happen after a If use handle but if you want never happen after if use second
and remove event

Comment: The words "so it doesn't need to be processed any further. In other words, please don't take any further action." are not really strictly true and they sound misleading to me. Setting `e.Handled = true` doesn't stop any further action unless the other handlers for that invocation of the event honour the `e.Handled` flag. A rogue handler could just continue to process what it wants to do and ignore it.

Comment: And what does "its depend to your Roll if you want not happen after a If use handle but if you want never happen after if use second and remove event" mean?

Comment: I'm sorry for saying this as English may not be your first language and I don't want to be rude, but the wording of this answer makes it nearly unintelligible so it's not very helpful.

Comment: if i want after doing some thing never run this event i remove the event but if i want at every time event happen check something i make event handle true or false